# PHP MYSQL AJAX Login data is correct but still php returns error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My problems is that whenever I try to login, I always get error message even if data is correct. I'm a beginner and I am building a website on WAMP. I have phpMyAdmin opened on next tab. Even if I input correct data, then also PHP will return error and it always goes into "Else" part.

Since I'm using AJAX, I'm not using `<form>` tag ... Ping me if I'm wrong somewhere

I am posting code below of Jquery and PHP + MySQL. Please help me... Thank you

Validation.js

```
var newEmailAddress = $('#myEmailAddress').val();
        var newUserPassword = $('#myUserPassword').val();

        var passData = 'LoginEmailAddress='+newEmailAddress+'&LoginPassword='+newUserPassword+'&Type=Login';

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "StoreData.php",
            data: passData,
            cache: false,

            success: function(data)
            {
                var data = $.parseJSON(data);

                if(data.statusType == 'LOGIN_SUCCESS')
                {
                    window.location = "Dashboard.php?DealerID="+data.sessionData;
                }

                if(data.statusType == 'LOGIN_FAILED')
                {
                    emailAddress.val(data.statusMessage);
                    userPassword.val(data.statusMessage);
                }
            }
        });
```

StoreData.php

```
session_start();

include "DatabaseConnection.php";

if($_POST['Type'] == "Login")
{
    $LoginEmailAddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($CreateConnection, $_POST['LoginEmailAddress']);
    $LoginPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($CreateConnection, md5($_POST['LoginPassword']));

    $FireLoginQuery = mysqli_query($CreateConnection, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email_address` = '".$LoginEmailAddress."' AND `password` = '".$LoginPassword."'");

    $SendLoginResponse = array();

    $FetchRows = mysqli_fetch_array($FireLoginQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if(!$FireLoginQuery)
    {
        echo mysqli_error();
    }

    else if(mysqli_num_rows($FireLoginQuery) == 1)
    {
        $SendLoginResponse['statusType'] == "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
        $_SESSION['ValidDealerID'] = $FetchRows['user_id'];
        $SendLoginResponse['sessionData'] = $_SESSION['ValidDealerID'];
    }

    else
    {
        $SendLoginResponse['statusType'] = "LOGIN_FAILED";
        $SendLoginResponse['statusMessage'] = "Wrong login credentials. Try again";
    }

    echo json_encode($SendLoginResponse);
}
```

DatabaseConnection.php (Just incase if anything's wrong)

```
 <?php

$ServerName = "localhost";
$Username = "root";
$Password = "";
$Database = "ruby";

$CreateConnection = mysqli_connect($ServerName, $Username, $Password);
$SelectDatabase = mysqli_select_db($CreateConnection, $Database);

if($CreateConnection == false)
{
    echo "There was a problem with database connection";
}

?>
```

The SQL Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    last_name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    email_address varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    current_address varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    permanent_address varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    cell_number varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    other_cell_number varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    security_question varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    security_answer varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=180
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hello jsve, It goes into Else block directly where I have set Wrong Credentials message. You can refer to my php code, I have pasted all necessary code blocks

Comment: What is your SQL table structure?

Comment: This code is also vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Print the actual query generated and run it in mysql. Maybe it just can't find any matching user and password.

Comment: @jsve Sorry for replying late. Here is my SQL table structure

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `current_address` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `permanent_address` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `cell_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `other_cell_number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `security_question` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `security_answer` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=180

Comment: @jsve I'm sorry but SQL injection is still possible if I use mysqli ? Can you please point out where I am lacking

Comment: @KushAcharya, anywhere that you have a SQL statement that is dependent on user input, there's a possibility for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Can you post a dump of the data, If you have multiple entries with the same email and password, you would fall into that error since your _else if_ is looking for only 1 row. If there were none, or more than one that could be a problem.

Comment: @Ron Sims II Hello Sir, I finally found out the problem. Actually I was making it very complicated. I just inserted form tag and directly processed the php code and it worked